# unique.data.table select last row in place of the first

Tags: r, data.table

calling `unique` on a keyed `data.table` you'll have unique lines per each group. In case of duplicated lines the first will be taken. When I need the take the last instead ( in general the last temporal transaction) I use `.SD[.N]`

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

dt <- data.table(id=sample(letters, 10000, T), var=rnorm(10000), key="id")

microbenchmark(unique(dt), dt[, .SD[.N], by=id])
Unit: microseconds
                   expr      min        lq    median       uq        max neval
             unique(dt)  570.882  586.1155  595.8975  608.406   3209.122   100
 dt[, .SD[.N], by = id] 6532.739 6637.7745 6694.3820 6776.968 208264.433   100
```

do you know a faster way to do the same?

Comment: I'm surprised `unique.data.table` and `duplicated.data.table` don't support the `fromLast` argument like `unique.data.frame` and `duplicated.data.frame`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a `data.table` that contains the unique combinations of the key variables then join using `mult = 'last'`

Using `.SD` is convenient, but slow. You could use `.I` instead if you wished.

```
dtu <- unique(dt)[,key(dt), with = FALSE]
dt[dtu, mult = 'last']
```

Or

```
 dt[ dt[,  .I[.N], by = key(dt)]$V1]
```

Comment: @Farrel In `?data.table` (under `by`) (`.I is an integer vector length .N holding the row locations in x for this group`)

Comment: That is blood clever, I think. Is this what is happening? The code creates and vector of the row numbers in dt that contain the Nth instance of a group, whereby a group is a collection of unique entries as defined by the key.

Answer (score 4):

From `data.table` v1.9.4, you can use `fromLast = TRUE`.

```
microbenchmark(unique(dt, by = "id"), 
               dt[, .SD[.N], by=id], 
               unique(dt, by = "id", fromLast = TRUE))

Unit: microseconds
                                   expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
                  unique(dt, by = "id") 333.978 355.1900 406.1585 371.1360 393.4015 3203.769   100  a 
                 dt[, .SD[.N], by = id] 519.320 541.4345 580.2176 553.6200 563.5490 2690.167   100   b
 unique(dt, by = "id", fromLast = TRUE) 338.190 366.4725 430.1296 380.9145 400.7730 4774.663   100  a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option, although it looks like it's slightly slower than the answers from @mnel, at least for the example.

```
dt[,list(var,RN=.N:1),by=id][RN==1L]
```